# fields_for alter the record name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I am struggling with figuring out how to change the record on the fly.

I want to the input field to change from people[name to people[][name]

```
<%= f.fields_for :people, nil, prefix: "people[]" do |fy| %>
<% 4.times.each do %>
        <div class="grid-1">
            <%= fy.text_field :name  %>
        </div>
  <% end %>

<% 4.times.each do %>
        <div class="grid-1">
            <%= fy.text_field :city  %>
        </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The output using michael second method with active record:

```
 year => [{":name"=>""}, {":name"=>""}, {":name"=>""}, {":name"=>"", ":city"=>""}, {":city"=>""}, {":city"=>""}, {":city"=>"", ":town"=>""}... etc]
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use model Person here?

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do here? I'm trying to understand why you want to prompt for the same field `:name` four times. By the way, you have a syntax error (dangling comma) in the listed code, so it's unclear whether this is even what you have attempted.

Comment: So i want to gather them in this form. {people: [{name:"ggg"}, {name:"ggg"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm leaving the original answer here as it shows how to handle this in a situation where you're using Rails with ActiveRecord.  The original inquisitor has clarified his question below so scroll down to see the answer to his clarified question.**

You need to add more people to your record.  Let's say you have this:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, inverse_of: :family
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family, inverse_of: :people
end
```

In your controller, just add some people:

```
def new
  @family = Family.new
  4.times { @family.people.build }
end
```

Then you'll have them.

Forgot, you then need to simplify your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :people do |person_form| -%>
  <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
<% end -%>
```

Rails will handle the rest.

**Clarified answer:**

The question now becomes how to do this in the absence of ActiveRecord.  In this case forget about using the form builder stuff (fields_for and friends).  Let's just build it by hand.

In general, when I build a form like this I want to be able to move between a structure in Ruby and the form itself.

In your case you want to end up with a Hash like this:

```
{ people: [{name:"ggg"}, {name:"ggg"}] }
```

We want to build a form like this:

```
    <% records = params[:records] || { people: [ { name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' } ] } -%>
    <%= form_tag nil, method: :get do -%>
      <% records[:people].each do |person| -%>
        <%= text_field_tag "records[people][][name]", person[:name] %>
      <% end -%>
      <%= submit_tag "submit" -%>
    <% end -%>
```

When you submit it you get this as your parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "records"=>{"people"=>[{"name"=>"name1"}, {"name"=>"name2"}]}, "commit"=>"submit"}
```

Let's say you expand it out so that "people" has "name" and "city", for instance.  It'll still work:

```
    <% records = params[:records] || { people: [ { name: 'name1', city: 'Nashville' }, { name: 'name2', city: 'Brentwood' } ] } -%>
    <%= form_tag nil, method: :get do -%>
      <% records[:people].each do |person| -%>
        <%= text_field_tag "records[people][][name]", person[:name] %>
        <%= text_field_tag "records[people][][city]", person[:city] %>
        <br />
      <% end -%>
      <%= submit_tag "submit" -%>
    <% end -%>
```

From parameters:

```
"records"=>{"people"=>[{"name"=>"name1", "city"=>"Nashville"}, {"name"=>"name2", "city"=>"Brentwood"}]}
```

If you want to force it to have a certain number of items there are a couple of different ways.  Note that in that case you would want to either enforce the number of items or specifically ignore blanks.  A small change like this accomplishes the task of making sure it always shows 4 sets of name/city:

```
    <% records = params[:records] || { people: [ { name: 'name1', city: 'Nashville' }, { name: 'name2', city: 'Brentwood' } ] } -%>
    <%= form_tag nil, method: :get do -%>
      <% 0.upto(3) do |x| -%>
        <%= text_field_tag "records[people][][name]", (records[:people][x][:name] rescue '') %>
        <%= text_field_tag "records[people][][city]", (records[:people][x][:city] rescue '') %>
        <br />
      <% end -%>
      <%= submit_tag "submit" -%>
    <% end -%>
```

This yields:

```
"records"=>{"people"=>[{"name"=>"name1", "city"=>"Nashville"}, {"name"=>"name2", "city"=>"Brentwood"}, {"name"=>"", "city"=>""}, {"name"=>"", "city"=>""}]}
```

One caveat here is that I'm just sticking all of this in a view for simplicity but you almost surely would want the first line (where "records" is set) to be in the controller using "@records".

Good luck!

Comment: I like your implementation.. but here we are not using ActiveRecord for this.. just plain old objects.. this because we are communicating with a legacy object.. Can you suggest ways this can be achieved without active record? Cheers

Comment: See the expanded answer above.

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I suppose we are pretty close.. The name and city in this case are rendered in rows horizontally 4 times.. I have updated the question above.Here is the output.. year => [{":name"=>""}, {":name"=>""}, {":name"=>""}, {":name"=>"", ":city"=>""}, {":city"=>""}, {":city"=>""}, {":city"=>"", ":town"=>""}... etc]